# How to develop multiple get router functions under same controller and same route in expressjs/nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express with Node and I have a requirement in which my client end application can request the similar URLs as

```
   http://localhost:3008/api/mitems/7
   http://localhost:3008/api/mitems/0/0/20
   http://localhost:3008/api/mitems/7/2/0/20
```

these requests will return a JSON response.

I have configured express to route as follows:

```
    router.get("/getbyId/:mid", mControllers.getById);
    
    router.get("/:mid/:pNo/:pSize", mControllers.getM);
    
    router.get("/:mid/:mItemId/:pNo/:pSize", mControllers.getMItems);
```

But this does not work properly. I am unsure of how to pass multiple parameters, that is, I am unsure if this is the correct way to do this. Is it?

Node considers first `router.get("/getbyId/:mid", mControllers.getById);` api with each different request whether I call from  `http://localhost:3008/api/mitems/0/0/20` or       `http://localhost:3008/api/mitems/7/2/0/20` but in both ways.

How should I overload the same API functions in nodejs or is there any better way to achieve this?

```
================================package.json===========================
{
  "name": "A Demos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a Demo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "test",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

The error , I am getting a nodejs  side

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as get] (s\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Function.proto.<computed> [as get] (s\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (s\routes\menus-routes.js:12:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (s\index.js:16:21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express considers routes in the order you add them to the `router`, and a request matches a route in a `router.get` statement if

- request and route have the same number of path segments
- a non-placeholder segment (that does not begin with `:`) in the route equals the corresponding path segment in the request.
- A placeholder segment (for example, `:mid`) then causes the corresponding path segment in the request to be stored in `req.params` (`req.params.mid` in this example).

Given the three routes from your question, and if `router` is mounted on the `/api` path:

| the request | is matched by | with `req.params` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `/api/mitems/7` | none of the routes |  |
| `/api/mitems/0/0/20` | `/:mid/:mItemId/:pNo/:pSize` | `{mid: "mitems", mItemId: "0", pNo: "0", pSize: "20"}` |
| `/api/mitems/7/2/0/20` | none of the routes |  |
| Moreover, `/api/getById/7` | `/getbyId/:mid` | `{mid: "7"}` |

(Perhaps there is a typo in your question?)

Note that matching rules are different when you replace `.get` with `.use`:

`app.use(<route>)` is matched even if the request has *more* segments than the route. With the `.use` method, you should therefore add the longer (more specific) route *before* the shorter (less specific) one.

Comment: Hi Heiko , How the longer route should be in this case ?

Comment: @tekf: Edited my answer accordingly.