# How to make a REST API with "two :id-parameter"-functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sqlite, rest

I´m making an API with node and express that fetches data from an SQLite database and sends as a response. My database is structured as follows:
I have a set of tables, one for each customer. These tables contain a set of rows, one for each page the customer has.

For example say that I have two customers; Fruit and Vegetables. The dream scenario would be that `localhost:8080/fruit` leads to a home page for Fruit, and that `localhost:8080/fruit/apples` leads to the apples-page for fruit, without me having to manually program all the specific routes. I know about the :id parameter in express, and the functionality I would like is basically using the :id twice, like `localhost:8080/:id1/:id2`.

Here´s my code:

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`It's alive on http://localhost:${PORT}`));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("start"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//* These is the router in use
import router from "../controller/router.js";

// * This defines what URI is used for the router
app.use("/", router);
```

```
import express from "express";
import { fetchContent } from "../model/model.js";

const router = express.Router();

//* Sends out the ejs (basically HTML) on start URL "localhost:8080"
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  converter();
  res.render("../pages/start.ejs");
});

//* Querys the database, the table ":id"
router.get("/:id", async function (req, res, next) {
  let id = req.params.id;
  let sqlQuery = `SELECT page_content FROM ${id} WHERE page_name = "about";`;
  const content = await fetchContent(sqlQuery);
  if (content == "404") {
    res.status(404).render("../pages/404.ejs");
  } else {
    res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(content));
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

```
import sqlite3 from "sqlite3";

const db = new sqlite3.Database(
  "path/to/my/db.db"
);

export function fetchContent(sqlQuery) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.all(sqlQuery, [], (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        resolve("404");
      } else {
        rows.forEach((row) => {
          resolve(row.page_content);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I have made this work with one :id, and the API fetches whatever table the :id is, but right now it´s a predetermined page, and I can´t go anywhere from there. If my explanation of what I would like was hard to follow just ask and I´ll try to explain better. :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to develop multiple get router functions under same controller and same route in expressjs/nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68983542/how-to-develop-multiple-get-router-functions-under-same-controller-and-same-rout)

Comment: Well the question and problem seems to be very close to what I have, but I don´t really understand the answer/solution...

Answer (score 0):

This was actually really simple. All I had to do was to make a new parameter. On my old code I had this:

```
router.get("/:id", async function (req, res, next) {
  let customerId = req.params.id;
  let sqlQuery = `SELECT page_content FROM ${id} WHERE page_name = "about";`;
});
```

But now I renamed the old one and made a new one, and now my code looks like this:

```
router.get("/:customerId", async function (req, res, next) {
  let customerId = req.params.customerId;
  let sqlQuery = `SELECT page_content FROM ${customerId} WHERE page_name = "about";`;
});

router.get("/:customerId/:pageId", async function (req, res, next) {
  let customerId = req.params.customerId;
  let pageId = req.params.pageId;
  let sqlQuery = `SELECT page_content FROM ${customerId} WHERE page_name = "${pageId}";`;
});
```